# Does ss:AutoFitHeight work for text?

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, xls

I have an XML file that I save as `.xls` to work on in Excel:

```
<results>
    <result>
        <companyName>Fnatic</companyName>
        <serviceID>1045</serviceID>
        <startDate>01-01-2014 00:00:00</startDate>
        <endDate>01-02-2014 00:00:00</endDate>
        <hours>1</hours>
        <description>Couple of paragraphs of text. Like 3 of them.</description>
    </result>
    ... more results
</results>
```

I use **Excel XML** to define structure and styles of the XML data. Only thing left to do is make it so the "Description" cell, that is merged set of columns, to adjust height automatically to the amount of text in it. `ss:Row` seems to have the `ss:AutoFitHeight`. But no changes happen to the resulting `.xls` file when I utilize them. Does `ss:AutoFitHeight` not work with text just like `ss:AutoFitWidth` doesn't work for text in `ss:Column`?

```
... rest of typical declarations

<xsl:template match="results">  

    <Styles>
        <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
          <Alignment ss:Vertical="Top" />
          <Borders />
          <Font />
          <Interior />
          <NumberFormat />
          <Protection />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s1">
          <Font ss:Size="10" ss:Bold="1" />
          <Interior ss:Color="#cef2ce" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
          <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Top" />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s2">
          <Interior ss:Color="#C0C0C0" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
        </Style>
      </Styles>


      <Worksheet ss:Name="Worksheet">
            <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
            <Column ss:Width="77" />
            <Column ss:Width="65" />
            <Column ss:Width="246" />
            <Column ss:Width="26" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="result" />
            <Row><!-- Last Row -->
                <Cell ss:Index="3"><Data ss:Type="String">Total:</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:Formula="=SUM(R[-{count(result)}]C:R[-1]C)">
                    <Data ss:Type="Number"></Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="result">
    <Row>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="serviceID" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="hours" />
    </Row>
    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="description" />
    </Row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="serviceID">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s1">
        <Data ss:Type="String">Service ID:</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s2">
        <Data ss:Type="Number">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Data>
    </Cell>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="description">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s1">
        <Data ss:Type="String">Description:</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:MergeAcross="2">
        <Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Data>
    </Cell>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="hours">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s1">
        <Data ss:Type="String">Hours:</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s2">
        <Data ss:Type="Number">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Data>
    </Cell>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: According to this answer, it might not always be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171849/excel-2003-xml-format-autofitwidth-not-working but you should check the reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140066(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: @helderdarocha That question is about `ss:AutoFitWidth` for `ss:Column` though. I saw the reference too and they don't mention anything about **NOT** supporting text with `ss:AutoFitHeight` for `ss:Row'. So it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the default row height on the column properties is counterintuitive and seems to contradict the specifications (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140066(v=office.10).aspx#odc_xmlss_ss:row), but it helps.